# Creating an Android trial application that expires after a fixed time period

Tags: android, trialware, android-1.5-cupcake

I have an application which I want to hit the market as a Paid app. I would like to have other version which would be a "trial" version with a time limit of say, 5 days?

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Google should really support this in Play Services!

Comment: @powder366 actually Google does support this, see https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Currently most developers accomplish this using one of the following 3 techniques.

The first approach is easily circumvented, the first time you run the app save the date/time to a file, database, or shared preferences and every time you run the app after that check to see if the trial period has ended.  This is easy to circumvent because uninstalling and reinstalling will allow the user to have another trial period.

The second approach is harder to circumvent, but still circumventable.  Use a hard coded time bomb.  Basically with this approach you will be hard code an end date for the trial, and all users that download and use the app will stop being able to use the app at the same time.  I have used this approach because it is easy to implement and for the most part I just didn't feel like going through the trouble of the third technique.  Users can circumvent this by manually changing the date on their phone, but most users won't go through the trouble to do such a thing.

The third technique is the only way that I have heard about to truly be able to accomplish what you want to do.  You will have to set up a server, and then whenever your application is started your app sends the [phones unique identifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()) to the server.  If the server does not have an entry for that phone id then it makes a new one and notes the time.  If the server does have an entry for the phone id then it does a simple check to see if the trial period has expired.  It then communicates the results of the trial expiration check back to your application.  This approach should not be circumventable, but does require setting up a webserver and such.

It is always good practice to do these checks in the onCreate.  If the expiration has ended popup an AlertDialog with a [market link](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent) to the full version of the app.  Only include an "OK" button, and once the user clicks on "OK" make a call to "finish()" to end the activity.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Like you say I feel the second option is possibly the best. Its a shame google themselves don't offer some sort of licensing system as it may encourage both small and bigger brand developers to produce even more android applications.

Comment: Do you need to set up your own server? It seems like the kind of thing someone else would have. This webpage:
http://www.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/eng/services/inms/time-services/network-time.html
seems to indicate they have a service you could use.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't check during startup. Your goal is to sell the app, not punish the user(that's just a bonus ;) If you have it set to check every 2 minutes while running, you let the user start doing something and then realize they should pay. If you make it really easy to pay and get back to work(I'm not sure if you can in Android) I think you'll sell more then checking during onCreate.

Comment: @Whaledawg: You do need to run your own server because the server is storing the phone id and time of first run in a database that is then compare to later
Also when you do the check is purely preference of the developer, I used the hard coded time bomb in a game with great results.  The whole app would load, but the user can only interact with the dialog that is seen, there is a button on that dialog that takes the user directly to the purchase page for the game.  Users don't seem to mind AFAIK since that game has been in the top 10 paid apps since the opening of the Android Market.

Comment: Currently using the first method. It looks like number 2 is not an option if you want to continue getting users to try your app. 3rd is definitely doable, but I will check the usage stats of my trial app to see if a lot of people keep using it longer then the 5 days.

Comment: Using the phones unique identifier will prevent the user to use the app on a new device. Using the line1Number would allow users to take their apps with them if they take their number with them.

Comment: For the 2nd approach would performing the check in onResume() and not onCreate() be better? onCreate() would only check the date when the app is just created wouldn't it?

Comment: To anyone reluctant to use option 3 because of the additional server setup, take a look at Parse.com - it's a synch.

Comment: @snctln-I have a small doubt...in method 3 how to get the date independent of the device's date (as it can b changed as told in method 2).

Comment: I worked on an open source solution based on method 3 (as bachelor thesis). See my answer below and the current status of this project https://github.com/MaChristmann/mobile-trial

Comment: @snctln What if you are making an offline app which doesn't need internet how can we force a trial period if we are in a situation like this becuause in this case user can just turn off the internet and the 3rd approach will also fail  ?

Comment: What is meant by hardcode end date of trial? Does that mean you will keep releasing new versions of the trial app forever with different hardcoded dates into the future?

Comment: In case someone does not scroll down far enough to see, there is an approach 4 solution, use the installed datetime from the package, and hard code your trial period. So if the app should only work for 5 days, check to see if that date has expired. The user would have to keep changing their day back to installed day to circumvent, which like it was said before, no one wants to do that for an app.

Comment: Someone could write a xposed module to defeat the third method

Comment: great answer. but look at a scenario like this. the person still have my code after the trail period is expired. i can surely stop the app to run after a specific day. but he/she can reverse engineer my app. so how do i just delete my source code. or make it scrambled so that the source code can not be found again by reverse engineering.

Comment: @snctln In third technique, Suppose my application is offline, I never use my application on internet connectivity. Then this method can also circumvent. In this situation, what should I have to do?

Comment: Does the deviceID changes after every OS upgrade ?

Answer (score 22):

I've developed a [Android Trial SDK](https://www.trialy.io) which you can simply drop into your Android Studio project and it will take care of all the server-side management for you (including offline grace periods).

To use it, simply

**Add the library to your main module's `build.gradle`**

```
dependencies {
  compile 'io.trialy.library:trialy:1.0.2'
}
```

**Initialize the library in your main activity's `onCreate()` method**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Initialize the library and check the current trial status on every launch
    Trialy mTrialy = new Trialy(mContext, "YOUR_TRIALY_APP_KEY");
    mTrialy.checkTrial(TRIALY_SKU, mTrialyCallback);
}
```

**Add a callback handler:**

```
private TrialyCallback mTrialyCallback = new TrialyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(int status, long timeRemaining, String sku) {
        switch (status){
            case STATUS_TRIAL_JUST_STARTED:
                //The trial has just started - enable the premium features for the user
                 break;
            case STATUS_TRIAL_RUNNING:
                //The trial is currently running - enable the premium features for the user
                break;
            case STATUS_TRIAL_JUST_ENDED:
                //The trial has just ended - block access to the premium features
                break;
            case STATUS_TRIAL_NOT_YET_STARTED:
                //The user hasn't requested a trial yet - no need to do anything
                break;
            case STATUS_TRIAL_OVER:
                //The trial is over
                break;
        }
        Log.i("TRIALY", "Trialy response: " + Trialy.getStatusMessage(status));
    }

};
```

To start a trial, call `mTrialy.startTrial("YOUR_TRIAL_SKU", mTrialyCallback);`
Your app key and trial SKU can be found in your [Trialy developer dashboard](https://www.trialy.io).

Comment: It requires data to be enabled?

Comment: trialy is not reliable

Comment: @AmirDe Hi Amir, could you let me know what isn't working for you? I'm happy to help, support@trialy.io Trialy is working great for 1000+ users

Comment: @Nick don't know the reason my device is running android lollipop, when i set day from dashboard, then day shows in negative value after few minutes, it says trial expired, even though i have many days still in dashboard. I also tested on nougat device, seems to be working fine on naugat. maybe it has some older android version compatibility issues

Comment: @sivaram The library uses caching to ensure that it responds with a useful result even if data isn't available. Data needs to be enabled only for the first launch (when you're registering the new install with Trialy)

Comment: @sivaram thanks for reply but i didn't turn off data during testing. that doesn't seem to be the reason.

Comment: @Nick is it possible to define a hardcoded End of Test, lets say until end of 2020?

Comment: I've developed ***an*** Android... "correct your post"

Answer (score 18):

This is an old question but anyways, maybe this will help someone.

In case you want to go with the ***most simplistic approach***(which ***will fail if*** the app is uninstalled/reinstalled or user changes device's date manually), this is how it could be:

```
private final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
private final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String installDate = preferences.getString("InstallDate", null);
    if(installDate == null) {
        // First run, so save the current date
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        Date now = new Date();
        String dateString = formatter.format(now);
        editor.putString("InstallDate", dateString);
        // Commit the edits!
        editor.commit();
    }
    else {
        // This is not the 1st run, check install date
        Date before = (Date)formatter.parse(installDate);
        Date now = new Date();
        long diff = now.getTime() - before.getTime();
        long days = diff / ONE_DAY;
        if(days > 30) { // More than 30 days?
             // Expired !!!
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Well actually if you are using SharedPreferences and Android 2.2 Froyo or above, as long as you implement the Data Backup APIs for Google Data Synchronization the user should not be able to escape this across devices or by uninstalling, only by going to Settings > Applications and clearing data. Also, the method on Date is `getTime` not `getTimeInMillis`.

Comment: Disagree, this will also fail if user changes Device's date manually and also what if User clears data manually?

Comment: @Caner this is good to chek with sharedprefrence but user wiil clear memory from seting->aplication manager and reuse then what will do?

Comment: @CoronaPintu, so that this approach will also be trying with firebase, this will make the perfect combination, and trial period will over even the app will uninstalled.

Comment: combine and add the approach with "strangetimes" answer, this will make the approach perfect.

Answer (score 10):

This question and the answer of **snctln** inspired me to work on a solution based on method 3 as my bachelor thesis. I know the current status is not for productive usage but I would love to hear what you think about it! Would you use such a system? Would you like to see it as a cloud service (not having trouble with configuring a server)? Concerned about security issues or stability reasons?

A soon as I finished the bachelor procedure I want to continue working on the software. So now its the time I need your feedback!

Sourcecode is hosted on GitHub https://github.com/MaChristmann/mobile-trial

Some information about the system:
- The system has three parts, a Android library, a node.js server and a configurator for managing multiple trial apps and publisher/developer accounts.

- It only supports time-based trials and it uses your (play store or other) account rather than a phone ID.
- For Android library it is based on the Google Play licensing verification library. I modified it to connect to the node.js server and additionally the library tries to recognize if a user changed the system date. It also caches a retrieved trial-license in AES encrypted Shared Preferences. You can configure the valid time of the cache with the configurator. If a user "clear data" the library will force a server-side check.
- Server is using https and also digital signing the license-check response. It has also an API for CRUD trial apps and users (publisher and developer). Similiar to Licensing Verfication Library developers can test their behaviour implementation in the trial app with test result. So you in the configurator you can explicit set your license response to "licensed", "not licensed" or "server error".
- If you update your app with an ass-kicking new feature you might want that everyone can try it again. In the configurator you can renew the trial license for users with expired licenses by setting a versioncode that should trigger this. For example user is running your app on versioncode 3 und you want him to try features of versioncode 4. If he updates the app or reinstall it he is able to use full trial period again because the server knows on which version he has tried it last time.
- Everything is under the Apache 2.0 license

Comment: You just saved my day, thank you for hard work. I just thought to write same solution of using encrypted configuration obtained just once and keeping public key inside application. So major problem I can see only how do you grant a license? You still may need some unique id carrying with a phone to avoid multiple grants.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest and **best** way to do this is the implement BackupSharedPreferences.

The preferences are preserved, even if the app is uninstalled and reinstalled.

Simply save the install date as a preference and you are good to go.

Here's the theory:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html

Here's the example:
[Android SharedPreferences Backup Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161530/android-sharedpreferences-backup-not-working)

Comment: The user can disable backup in the system settings.

Comment: And it works across re-installations only, not clearing app storage.

Answer (score 5):

***Approach 4: use the application install time.***

Since API level 9 (Android 2.3.2, 2.3.1, Android 2.3, GINGERBREAD) there are [firstInstallTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime) and [lastUpdateTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#lastUpdateTime) in `PackageInfo`.

To read more: 
[How to get app install time from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831333/how-to-get-app-install-time-from-android)

Comment: Can method 1 from snctln's answer be used with this reliably, without being easily circumvented, or does it have the same or similar problem?

Comment: I've tested this method. The good side is that it works even if data is cleared. The bad side is that it can be circumvented by a uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: can confirm: on my Pixel, uninstalling and reinstalling the app resets the first install time. that makes it pretty trivial for users to reset the trial

Answer (score 4):

After looking at all options in this and other threads, these are my findings

**Shared preferences, database**
Can be cleared in the android settings, lost after an app reinstall. [Can be backed up with android's backup mechanism](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup.html#Comparison) and will be restored after a reinstall. Backup may not always be available, though should be on most devices

**External storage (writing to a file)**
Not affected by a clear from the settings or a reinstall if we [don't write to the application's private directory](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). But: [requires you to ask the user for their permission at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow) in newer android versions, so this is probably only feasible if you need that permission anyways. Can also be backed up.

**[PackageInfo.firstInstallTime](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime)**
Is reset after a reinstall but stable across updates

**Sign in to some account**
Doesn't matter if it's their Google account via Firebase or one in your own server: the trial is bound to the account. Making a new account will reset the trial.

**Firebase anonymous sign in**
You can sign in a user anonymously and store data for them in Firebase. But [apparently a reinstall of the app and maybe other undocumented events may give the user a new anonymous ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733137/firebase-auth-anonymous-login#comment70707001_41733137), resetting their trial time. (Google themselves don't provide much documentation on this)

**ANDROID_ID**
[May not be available and may change under certain circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4799394/1396068), e.g factory reset. The opinions on whether it's a good idea to use this to identify devices seem to differ.

**Play Advertising ID**
May be reset by the user. [May be disabled by the user by opting out of ad tracking.](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#use_appropriate_identifiers)

**InstanceID**
[Reset on a reinstall](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#use_appropriate_identifiers). [Reset in case of a security event. Can be reset by your app.](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/)

Which (combination of) methods work for you depends on your app and on how much effort you think the average John will put into gaining another trial period. I would recommend steering clear of using **only** anonymous Firebase and Advertising ID due to their instability. A multi-factor approach seems like it will yield the best results. Which factors are available to you depends on you app and its permissions.

For my own app I found shared preferences + firstInstallTime + backup of the preferences to be the least intrusive but also effective enough method. You have to make sure you only request a backup after checking and storing the trial start time in the shared preferences. Values in the shared Prefs must have precedence over the firstInstallTime. Then user has to reinstall the app, run it once and then clear the app's data to reset the trial, which is quite a lot of work. On devices without a backup transport the user can reset the trial by simply reinstalling, though.

I've made that approach available as [an extensible library](https://github.com/karottenreibe/simpletrial).

Answer (score 3):

Now in the recent version of android free trial subscription has been added, you can unlock all your app's features only after buying the subscription within app for a free trial period.
This will let the user to use your app for a trial period , if the app is still uninstalled after the trial period then the subscription money will be transferred to you. 
I have not tried , but just sharing an idea.

[Here's documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#administering)

Comment: I wish this worked for single purchases. Only works for subscriptions, which can be annual or monthly.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best way to do this is to simply use the Firebase Realtime Database:

1) Add Firebase support to your app

2) Select 'Anonymous authentication' so that the user doesn't have to signup or even know what you're doing. This is guaranteed to link to the currently authenticated user account and so will work across devices.

3) Use the Realtime Database API to set a value for 'installed_date'. At launch time, simply retrieve this value and use this.

I've done the same and it works great. I was able to test this across uninstall / re-installs and the value in the realtime database remains the same. This way your trial period works across multiple user devices. You can even version your install_date so that the app 'resets' the Trial date for each new major release.

**UPDATE**: After testing a bit more, it seems anonymous Firebase seems to allocate a different ID in case you've got different devices and is not guaranteed between re-installs :/ The only guaranteed way is to use Firebase but tie it to their google account. This should work, but would require an extra step where the user first needs to login / signup.

I've thus far ended up with a slightly less elegant approach of simply checking against backed-up preferences and a date stored in preferences upon install. This works for data-centric apps where it's pointless for a person to re-install the app and re-enter all the data previously added, but would not work for a simple game.

Comment: I have your same requirement for my android app and i have my own database/webserver. Users does not require a login, So i was planning to save Device ID with the installed_date, would this work ?

Comment: @strangetimes, i think your solution works best, can you provide more info? thanks

Comment: This thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/41733137/1396068 suggests that after reinstalling the app you get a new user ID, I.e. a new trial period

Answer (score 1):

By definition, *all* paid Android apps on the market can be evaluated for 24 hours after purchase.

There's an 'Uninstall and Refund' button which changes to 'Uninstall' after 24 hours.

I'd argue this button is way too prominent!

Comment: Note the refund period is now only 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I come across this question while searching for the same problem, i think we can utilize free date api like http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now or some other date api to check for expiry of trail app. this way is efficient if you wish to deliver the demo and worried about payment and require fix tenure demo. :)

find the code below

```
public class ValidationActivity extends BaseMainActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    processCurrentTime();
    super.onResume();
}

private void processCurrentTime() {
    if (!isDataConnectionAvailable(ValidationActivity.this)) {
        showerrorDialog("No Network coverage!");
    } else {
        String urlString = "http://api.timezonedb.com/?zone=Europe/London&key=OY8PYBIG2IM9";
        new CallAPI().execute(urlString);
    }
}

private void showerrorDialog(String data) {
    Dialog d = new Dialog(ValidationActivity.this);
    d.setTitle("LS14");
    TextView tv = new TextView(ValidationActivity.this);
    tv.setText(data);
    tv.setPadding(20, 30, 20, 50);
    d.setContentView(tv);
    d.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    d.show();
}

private void checkExpiry(int isError, long timestampinMillies) {
    long base_date = 1392878740000l;// feb_19 13:8 in GMT;
    // long expiryInMillies=1000*60*60*24*5;
    long expiryInMillies = 1000 * 60 * 10;
    if (isError == 1) {
        showerrorDialog("Server error, please try again after few seconds");
    } else {
        System.out.println("fetched time " + timestampinMillies);
        System.out.println("system time -" + (base_date + expiryInMillies));
        if (timestampinMillies > (base_date + expiryInMillies)) {
            showerrorDialog("Demo version expired please contact vendor support");
            System.out.println("expired");
        }
    }
}

private class CallAPI extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urlString = params[0]; // URL to call
        String resultToDisplay = "";
        InputStream in = null;
        // HTTP Get
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            resultToDisplay = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return resultToDisplay;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        int isError = 1;
        long timestamp = 0;
        if (result == null || result.length() == 0 || result.indexOf("<timestamp>") == -1 || result.indexOf("</timestamp>") == -1) {
            System.out.println("Error $$$$$$$$$");
        } else {
            String strTime = result.substring(result.indexOf("<timestamp>") + 11, result.indexOf("</timestamp>"));
            System.out.println(strTime);
            try {
                timestamp = Long.parseLong(strTime) * 1000;
                isError = 0;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            }
        }
        checkExpiry(isError, timestamp);
    }

} // end CallAPI

public static boolean isDataConnectionAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info == null)
        return false;

    return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}

public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    if (is != null) {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();

        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return writer.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

its working solution.....

Comment: sure you can use, but in that case only your main activity would be able to check for expiry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i went about mine,
I created 2 apps one with trial activity the other without,

i uploaded the one without trial activity to play store as paid app,

and the one with trial activity as free app.

The free app on first launch has options for trial and store purchase,
if the user select store purchase it redirects to the store for the user to purchase
but if the user clicks trial it take them to the trial activity

NB: I used option 3 like @snctln but with modifications

**first**, i did not depend on the device time, i got my time from the php file that does the trial registration to the db,

**secondly**, i used the device serial number to uniquely identify each device,

**lastly**, the app depends on the time value returned from the server connection not its own time so the system can only be circumvented if the device serial number is changed, which is quite stressful for a user.

so here goes my code (for the Trial activity):

```
package com.example.mypackage.my_app.Start_Activity.activity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.onlinewisdom.cbn_app.R;
import com.example.mypackage.my_app.Start_Activity.app.Config;
import com.example.mypackage.my_app.Start_Activity.data.TrialData;
import com.example.mypackage.my_app.Start_Activity.helper.connection.Connection;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;

public class Trial extends AppCompatActivity {
    Connection check;
    SweetAlertDialog pDialog;
    TextView tvPleaseWait;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 0;

    String BASE_URL = Config.BASE_URL;
    String BASE_URL2 = BASE_URL+ "/register_trial/"; //http://ur link to ur API

    //KEY
    public static final String KEY_IMEI = "IMEINumber";

    private final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    private final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String installDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trial);

        preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        installDate = preferences.getString("InstallDate", null);

        pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
        pDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#008753"));
        pDialog.setTitleText("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        tvPleaseWait = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPleaseWait);
        tvPleaseWait.setText("");

        if(installDate == null) {
            //register app for trial
            animateLoader(true);
            CheckConnection();
        } else {
            //go to main activity and verify there if trial period is over
            Intent i = new Intent(Trial.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // close this activity
            finish();
        }

    }

    public void CheckConnection() {
        check = new Connection(this);
        if (check.isConnected()) {
            //trigger 'loadIMEI'
            loadIMEI();
        } else {
            errorAlert("Check Connection", "Network is not detected");
            tvPleaseWait.setText("Network is not detected");
            animateLoader(false);
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //Changes 'back' button action
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void animateLoader(boolean visibility) {
        if (visibility)
            pDialog.show();
        else
            pDialog.hide();
    }

    public void errorAlert(String title, String msg) {
        new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                .setTitleText(title)
                .setContentText(msg)
                .show();
    }

    /**
     * Called when the 'loadIMEI' function is triggered.
     */
    public void loadIMEI() {
        // Check if the READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already available.
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // READ_PHONE_STATE permission has not been granted.
            requestReadPhoneStatePermission();
        } else {
            // READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already been granted.
            doPermissionGrantedStuffs();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Requests the READ_PHONE_STATE permission.
     * If the permission has been denied previously, a dialog will prompt the user to grant the
     * permission, otherwise it is requested directly.
     */
    private void requestReadPhoneStatePermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Trial.this)
                    .setTitle("Permission Request")
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.permission_read_phone_state_rationale))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //re-request
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Trial.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.warning_sigh)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // READ_PHONE_STATE permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE) {
            // Received permission result for READ_PHONE_STATE permission.est.");
            // Check if the only required permission has been granted
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // READ_PHONE_STATE permission has been granted, proceed with displaying IMEI Number
                //alertAlert(getString(R.string.permision_available_read_phone_state));
                doPermissionGrantedStuffs();
            } else {
                alertAlert(getString(R.string.permissions_not_granted_read_phone_state));
            }
        }
    }

    private void alertAlert(String msg) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(Trial.this)
                .setTitle("Permission Request")
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do somthing here
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(R.drawable.warning_sigh)
                .show();
    }

    private void successAlert(String msg) {
        new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                .setTitleText("Success")
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setConfirmText("Ok")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                        sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                        // Prepare intent which is to be triggered
                        //Intent i = new Intent(Trial.this, MainActivity.class);
                        //startActivity(i);
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    public void doPermissionGrantedStuffs() {
        //Have an  object of TelephonyManager
        TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //Get IMEI Number of Phone  //////////////// for this example i only need the IMEI
        String IMEINumber = tm.getDeviceId();

        /************************************************
         * **********************************************
         * This is just an icing on the cake
         * the following are other children of TELEPHONY_SERVICE
         *
         //Get Subscriber ID
         String subscriberID=tm.getDeviceId();

         //Get SIM Serial Number
         String SIMSerialNumber=tm.getSimSerialNumber();

         //Get Network Country ISO Code
         String networkCountryISO=tm.getNetworkCountryIso();

         //Get SIM Country ISO Code
         String SIMCountryISO=tm.getSimCountryIso();

         //Get the device software version
         String softwareVersion=tm.getDeviceSoftwareVersion()

         //Get the Voice mail number
         String voiceMailNumber=tm.getVoiceMailNumber();


         //Get the Phone Type CDMA/GSM/NONE
         int phoneType=tm.getPhoneType();

         switch (phoneType)
         {
         case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
         // your code
         break;
         case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM)
         // your code
         break;
         case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE):
         // your code
         break;
         }

         //Find whether the Phone is in Roaming, returns true if in roaming
         boolean isRoaming=tm.isNetworkRoaming();
         if(isRoaming)
         phoneDetails+="\nIs In Roaming : "+"YES";
         else
         phoneDetails+="\nIs In Roaming : "+"NO";


         //Get the SIM state
         int SIMState=tm.getSimState();
         switch(SIMState)
         {
         case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT :
         // your code
         break;
         case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED :
         // your code
         break;
         case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED :
         // your code
         break;
         case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED :
         // your code
         break;
         case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY :
         // your code
         break;
         case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN :
         // your code
         break;

         }
         */
        // Now read the desired content to a textview.
        //tvPleaseWait.setText(IMEINumber);
        UserTrialRegistrationTask(IMEINumber);
    }

    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    private void UserTrialRegistrationTask(final String IMEINumber) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, BASE_URL2+IMEINumber, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        TrialData result = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(response), TrialData.class);
                        animateLoader(false);
                        if ("true".equals(result.getError())) {
                            errorAlert("Error", result.getResult());
                            tvPleaseWait.setText("Unknown Error");
                        } else if ("false".equals(result.getError())) {
                            //already created install/trial_start date using the server
                            // so just getting the date called back
                            Date before = null;
                            try {
                                before = (Date)formatter.parse(result.getResult());
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Date now = new Date();
                            assert before != null;
                            long diff = now.getTime() - before.getTime();
                            long days = diff / ONE_DAY;
                            // save the date received
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putString("InstallDate", String.valueOf(days));
                            // Commit the edits!
                            editor.apply();
                            //go to main activity and verify there if trial period is over
                            Intent i = new Intent(Trial.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            // close this activity
                            finish();
                            //successAlert(String.valueOf(days));
                            //if(days > 5) { // More than 5 days?
                                // Expired !!!
                            //}
                            }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        animateLoader(false);
                        //errorAlert(error.toString());
                        errorAlert("Check Connection", "Could not establish a network connection.");
                        tvPleaseWait.setText("Network is not detected");
                    }
                })

        {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_IMEI, IMEINumber);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }


}
```

My php file looks like this (its a REST-slim technology):

```
/**
     * registerTrial
     */
    public function registerTrial($IMEINumber) {
        //check if $IMEINumber already exist
        // Instantiate DBH
        $DBH = new PDO_Wrapper();
        $DBH->query("SELECT date_reg FROM trials WHERE device_id = :IMEINumber");
        $DBH->bind(':IMEINumber', $IMEINumber);
        // DETERMINE HOW MANY ROWS OF RESULTS WE GOT
        $totalRows_registered = $DBH->rowCount();
        // DETERMINE HOW MANY ROWS OF RESULTS WE GOT
        $results = $DBH->resultset();

        if (!$IMEINumber) {
            return 'Device serial number could not be determined.';
        } else if ($totalRows_registered > 0) {
            $results = $results[0];
            $results = $results['date_reg'];
            return $results;
        } else {
            // Instantiate variables
            $trial_unique_id = es_generate_guid(60);
            $time_reg = date('H:i:s');
            $date_reg = date('Y-m-d');

            $DBH->beginTransaction();
            // opening db connection
            //NOW Insert INTO DB
            $DBH->query("INSERT INTO trials (time_reg, date_reg, date_time, device_id, trial_unique_id) VALUES (:time_reg, :date_reg, NOW(), :device_id, :trial_unique_id)");
            $arrayValue = array(':time_reg' => $time_reg, ':date_reg' => $date_reg, ':device_id' => $IMEINumber, ':trial_unique_id' => $trial_unique_id);
            $DBH->bindArray($arrayValue);
            $subscribe = $DBH->execute();
            $DBH->endTransaction();
            return $date_reg;
        }

    }
```

then on the main activity i use the shared preference (installDate created in trial activity) to monitor the number of days remaining and if the days are over i block the main activity UI with a message that takes them to the store to purchase.

The only down side i see here is that if a **Rogue user** buys the paid app and decides to share with apps like Zender, file share or even host the apk file directly on a server for people to download for free. But am sure i will soon edit this answer with a solution to that or a link to the solution.

Hope this saves a soul...some day

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

**@snctln** option 3 can be easily done adding a php file to a web server with php and mysql installed as many of them have.

From the Android side an identifier (the device ID, google account o whatever you want) is passed as argument in the URL using HttpURLConnection and the php returns the date of the first install if it exist in the table or it inserts a new row and it return the current date.

It works fine for me.

If I have time I will post some code !

Good Luck !

Comment: wait but do you loose your unique id after app reinstall ?!!

Comment: This ID identifies the hardware, the phone itself, the user does not see it and can not change it. If he reinstalls the app the php web service will detect that it is the same phone. On the other hand, if the user change the phone he will enjoy a new period.