# How can I make my beta expire?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android application I wish to release commercially. Before doing so I would like to release a beta. What methods can I use to cause the beta to expire/become unusable after 12 weeks?

Comment: Upon further inspection my question appears to be a duplicate. A question with a code sample of what to use is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/1223552/957245

Comment: This isn't a duplicate but explains our options nicely:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/995719/957245

Comment: @chris see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256306/321731

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check if the current date is not larger then the expiry date, eventually checking it with internet time server. And make sure you save each time you check it to the preferences, so the user has no use in rewinding time.

Anyway, you can expect that if somebody really wants to hack your app he can do it. So it's no use to completely focus on avoiding that.

Comment: Maybe OP can use hash function to generate hashed key (SHA256 or whatever) with his own salt + password key + timestamp but he may need to keep track of these keys for every download :)