# How to get app install time from android

Tags: android

i try some method,but not success,help me.

Comment: Could you add a few hundred words explaining what you are referring to?

Comment: I guess he wants to know when an app was installed.

Comment: who tell me,how to get List application installed ,it installed by user,nou system.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("app.package.name", 0);
String appFile = appInfo.sourceDir;
long installed = new File(appFile).lastModified(); //Epoch Time
```

Comment: Also, this should show the last install ***or update*** time.

Comment: How about the actual first install time and NOT the update time?

Comment: see @orip's answer for that

Answer (score 61):

In API level 9 (Gingerbread) and above, there's the [PackageInfo.firstInstallTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime) field, holding milliseconds since the epoch:

```
packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).firstInstallTime;
```

I have the following code to use it if available, and fall back to the apk modification time:

```
// return install time from package manager, or apk file modification time,
// or null if not found
public Date getInstallTime(
    PackageManager packageManager, String packageName) {
  return firstNonNull(
    installTimeFromPackageManager(packageManager, packageName),
    apkUpdateTime(packageManager, packageName));
}

private Date apkUpdateTime(
    PackageManager packageManager, String packageName) {
  try {
    ApplicationInfo info = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
    File apkFile = new File(info.sourceDir);
    return apkFile.exists() ? new Date(apkFile.lastModified()) : null;
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    return null; // package not found
  }
}

private Date installTimeFromPackageManager(
    PackageManager packageManager, String packageName) {
  // API level 9 and above have the "firstInstallTime" field.
  // Check for it with reflection and return if present. 
  try {
    PackageInfo info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    Field field = PackageInfo.class.getField("firstInstallTime");
    long timestamp = field.getLong(info);
    return new Date(timestamp);
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {        
    return null; // package not found
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  } catch (SecurityException e) {
  }
  // field wasn't found
  return null;
}

private Date firstNonNull(Date... dates) {
  for (Date date : dates)
    if (date != null)
      return date;
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Why is it called `firstInstallTime` ? Why first? Upon removal, it won't be restored on the next installation of it, no?

Answer (score 18):

[PackageInfo.firstInstallTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime) gives you the install time in *"Unix time"* (the time in milliseconds since *"the epoch"*, i.e. *January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC*). You may use [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or [java.text.DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) in order to format this time.

```
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

...
packageName = ...
...

try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

    Date installTime = new Date( packageInfo.firstInstallTime );
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed: " + installTime.toString());

    Date updateTime = new Date( packageInfo.lastUpdateTime );
    Log.d(TAG, "Updated: " + updateTime.toString());
}
catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also change the date format with [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String installTime = dateFormat.format( new Date( packageInfo.firstInstallTime ) );
Log.d(TAG, "Installed: " + installTime);

String updateTime = dateFormat.format( new Date( packageInfo.lastUpdateTime ) );
Log.d(TAG, "Updated: " + updateTime);
```

Comment: Its unnecessary to request "PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS" from the packagemanager if you only want those 2 times (just pass "0")

Comment: How come it's called `firstInstallTime` ? Why first? Upon removal, it won't be restored on the next installation of it, no?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from 2022, and it's working for me.

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
long firstInstallTime = pi.firstInstallTime;
long lastUpdateTime = pi.lastUpdateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

First install time as Kotlin extension:

```
fun Context.getFirstInstallDate(): Date? =
    try {
        val time: Long = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).firstInstallTime
        Date(time)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
```