# android lvl check if purchased app is in the refund period

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am using LVL to add licensing to my app. I was wondering if i can check if the person that purchased the app is still able to get a refund (is using the app within 15 minutes of the purchase). Anyone got some examples or directions he can give me for this sort of thing?

Or maybe an alternative: to check when the app was installed on the phone.
i found this link -> [installTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831333/how-to-get-app-install-time-from-android/2832419#2832419)

But something was unclear:

the app source directory is never modified after install?

What about after update?

also found this comment in the licensing/ServerManagedPolicy.java:

```
 * These values will vary based on the the way the application is configured in
 * the Android Market publishing console, such as whether the application is
 * marked as free or is within its refund period, as well as how often an...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the DateTime in the app and save it as a Preference when you start the app. Then evaluate it at some point to find out if 15 minutes has passed.

Comment: that wasn't really what i was looking for at the time.i wanted a more reliable way of doing this sort of thing, sadly i couldn't find one.

Comment: Unfortunately Google does not seem to ant to let people restrict the use of the application for the 15 minutes that they can return it. Its supposed to be a trial of the full version of the application