# How to determine if user is reinstalling the app on Android

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am working on adding a release notes webView when our app is installed either for the very first time or when the app is being reinstalled.  My question is on the second part where the user is installing the app on top of an existing one.  I thought about deleting the release notes after it is installed but it's not possible to delete a file from assets at run time. Is there a way to determine this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "reinstalled"? - Do you mean the already installed App is updated?

Comment: by reinstalled i mean update..the app was already installed and I am installing a newer apk on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about saving the time when the release note was last shown in `SharedPreferences`, and checking it against the app install time? On fresh install there will be nothing in `SharedPreferences`, so you know you need to show the release note.

You can get the app install time this way:
[How to get app install time from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831333/how-to-get-app-install-time-from-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), regular File IO, or an SQLite DB in your app to store persistent information, e.g. a flag indicating if the current release notes have already been displayed or not. This data will "survive" an update of your App.
These data will, however, be deleted when the App is uninstalled from the phone, but I guess that's not a problem in your case.

Comment: I want the release notes to show up on the first launch after a fresh install or an update. I believe setting the shredpreferences value will not bring up the release notes (first launch) after the update or I am missing your point?

Comment: Emphasis is on *current* release notes :) You don't need install time or the like. Just say, you update your app with v2.3 and upon the first start of the new version you find your app previously stored "LastChangeNoteVersion=V1.9"; you'll show the notes in this case and update the persistent value "LastChangeNoteVersion" or whatever.