# Identify device with React Native across multiple app installs

Tags: react-native, expo

Since getting IMEI or other device IDs is not allowed, what is the best way to identify the same device across multiple react native app installs/re-installs? I would like to know if this is the same devices installing the same application again.

If relevant, this would be for a react native application with expo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question has been already answered here. Please check this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884694/how-to-determine-if-user-is-reinstalling-the-app-on-android)

Comment: we use it for production, id only changes on hard reset https://stackoverflow.com/a/71305727/18341393

Comment: I am not sure if the linked items are exactly what I am looking for. one talks about knowing when the app is installed, which is super easy since your async store is clean.. the other is mostly for iOS only and it is not clear if secure store is kept after app delete since I see some comments questioning that. also would that require new permissions? and what is the equivalent of that for Android?

Comment: there is a note in the expo-secure-store docs: " Please note that for iOS standalone apps, data stored with expo-secure-store can persist across app installs." if you will use androidId, then you need to fill in the data collection section in google play

Comment: for androidId, do you know which part of the data collection section is affected by that?