# Android: how can I show a button one day after installation?

Tags: android, visible

there is a button in my main activity . by default its invisible but I wanna make it visible one day after installation of my app (or one day after first run of my app ).
so when the user install my app he can't see my button . but one day after installation he can see my button.
how can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831333/how-to-get-app-install-time-from-android and then check if passed a day. (p.s you could cache this value somewhere to don't execute it everytime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution...
Firstly get the installation date then compare that date with current date. if its greater than 1 day you can show your button.

Here is the code...

```
// ****************** To know installation date of application for button show **************//
    try {
        appInstalledDate = Splash.this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your package name", 0).firstInstallTime;
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM,yyyy HH:mm");
            Date resultdate = new Date(appInstalledDate);
        Log.v("Installation date of app is ",","+resultdate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here you can show your button

```
try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");

                Date resultdate = new Date(Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("email_prompt", "")));
                                    Log.v("current date ",","+sdf.format(new Date().getTime()));
                long diff = new Date().getTime() - resultdate
                long diffMinutes = (diff / 1000) / 60;
                long diffMinutes = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff));
                Log.v("Difference in minutes is ",","+diffMinutes);

                if(1440 < diffMinutes)
                {
                 yourButton.show(); // show your button

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Store a boolean in `SharedPreferences` (SP) called `hasRunOnce` set it to a default of `false`.
2. In `onCreate` and inside an `if` clause for which the SP `hasRunOnce` must be false, store current time in milliseconds (`System.currentTimeMillis()` will work but you'll need to cast the `Long`) to an Integer in `SharedPreferences` called `installTime` and set the SP `hasRunOnce` to `true` (so we'll never again re-store the system time).
3. In `onCreate` (or `onResume`) and inside of an `if` clause for which the current system time must be greater than `installTime` plus 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 (a day's worth of milliseconds), put in the logic to make your `Button` view visible.

Answer (score 0):

Your first doing getting system time and app first running time. before I advice your look up this two links

[get android current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271131/display-the-current-time-and-date-in-an-android-application)

[get app first running time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-the-first-time-used)

and your make if condition on your activity it seems

```
if(sysDateTime - appFirstRunTime > 24){
   yourButton.visiblty = true;
```