# How to create a 30 day free trial Android app?

Tags: android, trialware

Is there any way to receive the installation date of an Android app? Or any other suggestions on how to accomplish a 30 day free trial version?

Comment: I think this may be against the android market terms of service. You should probably check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This already has a pretty good answer:

[Creating an Android trial application that expires after a fixed time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995719/android-trial-applications)

Answer (score 3):

Just save the time when the application was first run. Then compare the time each time the program starts.

Another more secure way (the above tactic could be beaten by a simple reinstall) is to have a server of yours authenticate the imei number of the device the first time it's run and then continue the above method.