# What should the Android device ID length be

Tags: android, udid

Can anybody please tell me the length for device UDID in Android, because I got the UDID in android and it is only 16 characters, but the iPhone UDID length is 40.

I am using the following code to detect the ID:

```
id = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(super.getContentResolver(),
    android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: how are you obtaining the uuid? Also I don't think a specific size is enforced, so it would be safer if you did not assume that the length will be the same across all Android devices.

Comment: id = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(super.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

Comment: i just analyse the length (UDID) for iphone and  android

Comment: oh, Im sorry I did not realize that you were the asker. Don't post in an answer edit your question to include the code.

Answer (score 11):

The Android ID is

### **UP TO 16 characters long**

since leading zeroes are not pretended at least in some versions of Android that appear in the wild. Take a look at this answer to a similar question for why that is:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29890124/2066744

The docs specify it as *a 64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string)* here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Answer (score 8):

i have two device using this code

```
String device_id =  Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: be aware that this method of getting a UID is not bullet proof. See: [Is Secure.ANDROID_ID unique for each device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799394/is-secure-android-id-unique-for-each-device) and [Is there a unique Android device ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) for reference. Use at your own risk =)

Comment: Got a 15 as well.