# Secure Android ID length?

Tags: android, udid

I am using the below code to get the android ID

```
 String android_id = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

I am able to get the android ID but it's length is not fixed. In some phones I get a 16 length ID and in other I get 15 length ID.

I read in the documentation it is a 64 Hex decimal number so it should always return 16 digit string.

So is there something wrong I am doing?

Comment: May be Android supresses leading zeros?

Comment: So i should just append "0" in the start. Will that be the right approach?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following [code snippet from AOSP](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/0a63944d29c27f4f7332500ffa3330e7eecf0e07/packages/SettingsProvider/src/com/android/providers/settings/SettingsProvider.java#L3535) shows how the ANDROID_ID is generated:

```
String androidId = Long.toHexString(new SecureRandom().nextLong());
```

The method `Long.toHexString` is known to suppress leading zeros. Therefore prepending the ANDROID_ID with zeros in case it's length is less than 16 should be to correct way to get a full 16 digits ANDROID_ID.