# Algorithm behind Secure.ANDROID_ID

Tags: java, android

Anyone know the code that generates Secure.ANDROID_ID? I want to generate Secure.ANDROID_ID from a Java program. From my understating it's a random 64 bit hex string?

Comment: A while ago I answered this question in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29890124/150978