# How to get android id in java without using of the class Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I can't using the following method because my class doesn't extends the Activity class:
[Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: pass the context object to the method.

Comment: Make your class Member object static . Then You can use like `Class.member` will work.

Comment: Take a look at these questions -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078269/android-unique-serial-number/16929647#16929647

Comment: Thanks for all answers, But because I didn't using the activity class, I cant access to the context object. I do instrumentation to another apk and this is the reason that I cant use the activity class.

All your solutions deals using with the Activity class (directly or indirectly)

Comment: ...send the Context in a constructor parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

public class sample {


    public String getId(Context c)
    {

         String android_id = Secure.getString(c.getContentResolver(),
                                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID); 

         return android_id;
    }
}
```

pass the context from your activity

```
sample s=new sample();

    String udid=s.getId(getApplicationContext());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), udid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
But because I didn't using the activity class, I cant access to the context object.
I do instrumentation to another apk and this is the reason that I cant use the activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public class Sample {


public static String getId(Context c)
{

     String android_id = Secure.getString(c.getContentResolver(),
                                                                Secure.ANDROID_ID); 

     return android_id;
    }
}
```

when you need the device id

```
String id = Sample.getId(youractivity.this);// if ur in an activity
```

or try this

```
 String id =Sample.getId(getApplicationContext());
```