# Why IMEI changes when I insert or remove SIM card?

Tags: android, sim-card, imei

I have used `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` for creating serial number for my android application. Now I have noticed it is changed when the user insert or removed SIM card!!!

Why this happens? My device is Samsung Galaxy SM-T211

How can I stop it?

It is an unbearable embarrassment for me to face my customers :((((

Comment: why you don't use mac Address of wifi or `Secure#ANDROID_ID` ?

Comment: some devices does not have wifi so it is null. another amazing problem is when the wifi is off it returns null!!!!!!!!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078269/android-unique-serial-number/16929647#16929647 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: The value of `ANDROID_ID` changes if a factory reset is performed on the device

Comment: yes but my mean is `android.os.Build.SERIAL`

Comment: documents: A hardware serial number, if available. When is not it available?

Comment: see this link that I post earlier ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078269/android-unique-serial-number ) this tell completely, if you say IMEI have been changed you can use emmby's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device