# Device unique ID that be persistent while not using device info

Tags: android, uuid

I used device information to create unique ID for android device but after i read Security Tips of google, want to change it somehow.

[Quote from Google](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Permissions):

If it's possible to design your application in a way that does not require any permissions, that is preferable. For example, rather than requesting access to device information to create a unique identifier, create a [GUID](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html) for your application.

How can i have a Unique ID for a Device that doesn't change next time app runs or device reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below method:

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

that returns unique android id. and don't need any permissions.

Also you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id).

Comment: Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID  is indeed device info!

Comment: oh, i see. you are right but i think it isn't unique and [there is a small chance that 2 android IDs be the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799394/is-secure-android-id-unique-for-each-device).  [and also](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID):  When a device has multiple users (available on certain devices running Android 4.2 or higher), each user appears as a completely separate device, so the ANDROID_ID value is unique to each user.

Comment: But during factory reset, this ID will get changed right ?

Comment: Maybe @Firnaz !!! Also it's known to be null sometimes and documented as "can change upon factory reset". Use at your own risk, and I should say it can be easily changed on a rooted phone

Answer (score 0):

you can use IMEI number which is unique to every phone but you need to ask

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

during runtime above api 23 and above.

Comment: so what do you think about google post? is it possible to have unique ID without problem and not using permissions?

Comment: using Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID) can give you unique id without having to ask for permission but from what i know, this value may change upon factory reset.