# How to get app specific ANDROID_ID on Android Oreo?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43393373/3951400) Oreo has unique ANDROID_ID's for each app which makes the previous command for getting the id not working as I'd like.

```
adb shell settings get secure android_id
```

How can I now, on Oreo, get the android id as seen by a specific app?

Root & non-root solutions are welcomed.

Comment: Related: [Where is the “android_id” stored and when does it change?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219757/218526)

Answer (score 2):

`adb` doesn't support retrieving an app-specific `ANDROID_ID` at this time, because app-specific ANDROID_IDs are being written into a separate file (`settings_ssaid.xml`, while `adb` allows to access only values from `system`, `secure` or `global` tables). However, on emulator or on a rooted device this can be easily achieved:

```
# switch into a root mode and open a shell
$ adb root
$ adb shell
$ pm list users
Users:
    UserInfo{0:Owner:13} running
    UserInfo{10:New user:10} running
# let's find all the app-specific ANDROID_IDs for user 0
$ cd /data/system/users/0
$ cat settings_ssaid.xml  
<settings version="-1">
  <setting id="0" name="userkey" value="E4FC4CFF14039F5AD44AD63F70007F85FDBBE1FF9BCB9FF5331B3FD33E057461" package="android" defaultValue="E4FC4CFF14039F5AD44AD63F70007F85FDBBE1FF9BCB9FF5331B3FD33E057461" defaultSysSet="true" tag="null" />
  <setting id="4" name="10072" value="9d5f269e42d4ca76" package="info.osom.ssaid" defaultValue="9d5f269e42d4ca76" defaultSysSet="false" tag="null" />
</settings>
```

In this example, I have one application with package name `info.osom.ssaid`, whose `ANDROID_ID` value is `9d5f269e42d4ca76`.