# ANDROID_ID after factory reset

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier, android-identifiers

According to the [google documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID) about `ANDROID_ID`, its value is unique until factory reset has done. I have a question about new generated `ANDROID_ID` after factory reset .

Is this value unique as old value? Is it possible that the new value is not unique?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799394/is-secure-android-id-unique-for-each-device):

> However, the value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device. There is also a known bug with a popular handset from a manufacturer where every instance have the same ANDROID_ID. Clearly, the solution is not 100% reliable.