Understand the `per user` part in Android ID uniqueness
I understand the per app and per app-signin part of this statement. But I don't understand the per-user part.

On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher versions of the platform, a
64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each
combination of app-signing key, user, and device

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID
I read several SO posts but could not find an explanation of the per user part.

With Android O the behaviour of the ANDROID_ID will change. The
ANDROID_ID will be different per app per user on the phone.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43393373/6727914
Android_ID in Android O
When I go my device settings, it says "Samsung Account" with the email  I used to create a Samsung account and "Logout" at the bottom, that's all. Does the per-user refers that that account ?

My assumptions was that the user refers to the Google Account the user used to download the app on Play Store. To validate, I:

Built a simple Android that displays the Android ID
Published to Play Store
Downloaded with a Google Account A)
Removed and Downloaded with a Google Account B) on the same device.

However, the Android ID on 3) and 4) are the same. So the user does not the Google Play Store account.

I found this on the Android Developer documentation.

In versions of the platform lower than Android 8.0 (API level 26), a
64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string) that is randomly
generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain
constant for the lifetime of the user's device. On devices that have
multiple users, each user appears as a completely separate device, so
the ANDROID_ID value is unique to each user.

But it seems confusing as they refer to OS Lower than Android 8.0.

I have two questions, do all device support Multiple user or it is manufacturer/brand/model dependant ? (I have a Samsung phone and I can't find where to create multiple)

If you device supports multiple users, Can you show how to create multiple users on the same device that make Android ID different (with screenshots possibly ?).

Finally, if a device supports multiple users, how "easy" is it to create such accounts and is there a limit on how many users a device can have ? If my app uses Android ID for promotional offer limiting one per Device, wouldn't that be a vulnerability ?




do all device support Multiple user or it is manufacturer/brand/model dependant ?

The OS has supported multiple users for quite some time (my guess is around a decade). Whether a manufacturer chooses to offer a Settings UI for it, and where it resides in the Settings app, is a separate matter.

do all device support Multiple user or it is manufacturer/brand/model dependant ?


On a Pixel 8a running Android 14, go to Settings > System > Multiple Users

On a Samsung Galaxy Tab S8+, go to Settings > Accounts and backup > Users




how "easy" is it to create such accounts

If the Settings UI offers it, it is very easy.

is there a limit on how many users a device can have ?

Probably, though I do not know what it is.

If my app uses Android ID for promotional offer limiting one per Device, wouldn't that be a vulnerability ?

Nobody should be using ANDROID_ID for much of anything, IMHO. And doing anything "one per Device" is going to be a problem, because the industry is trying very, very hard to get away from unique device identifiers, for privacy and security reasons.

I think they have recommend using the Advertising ID to address the privacy concern, which is resettable

@TSR: Agreed, and because it is resettable it might be a bad choice for "promotional offer limiting one per Device".
