# How to avoid giving free trial of the Application's In-App Subscription to users who already have consumed it?

Tags: android, ios, in-app, in-app-subscription

The problem I am facing is, A user can get the free trial benefits without any restriction of my In-App purchase by creating and logging in with new Apple or Google ID on their device.

I can maintain the list of users who already have consumed the free trial as the app requires sign-in and I can map that purchase with the account, but the Apple and Google won't recognise that user as the existing user for that purchase and will give the free trial benefit again without charging anything.

The one solution I came up with is to **keep two Product ID** on respective stores like:

1. **my_in_app_subscription_with_trial**: It will give any new user the benefits of Free trials.
2. **my_in_app_subscription_without_trial**: It will start the subscription the moment the user buys it. I can use this for those users who already have consumed the free trial.

or

Is there any way to give users free trial of In-App Subscription conditionally while requesting for Subscription from Respective Stores?

**Any suggestions other than the above-mentioned?**

I looked at this question [Android in-app purchase of a subscription with a free trial - how to avoid abuse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612177/android-in-app-purchase-of-a-subscription-with-a-free-trial-how-to-avoid-abuse)

But the above scenario is taken care by Google and Apple.

Comment: On iOS you can use the DeviceCheck framework to record a bit that indicates that a particular device has already used a free trial.

Comment: Hey @Paulw11 thanks for the response, I can know about trial from the account the user used for Signing In to my application. I am asking how can I restrict the user to get the trial period again and that is being handled by Apple and Google.

Comment: It's really hard to do this.  You need an entire server-side to check and process everything.

Comment: I got the server side of the Application, please tell me how can I control Apple and Google Subscriptions to not let particular users to access trial period?

Comment: If the user has to log in to your account system before they can purchase a subscription then you can check whether they have had a trial before and then offer the appropriate in-app purchase. If they don't login first then you can't. You can use DeviceCheck to see if this device has had a free trial before and again offer the appropriate in-app purchase.  Chances are you might be overthinking it. Continually creating new Apple IDs is a lot of work. Also, iOS only allows so many App Store account changes on a device before it locks out changes for 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

On Google Play, you can call queryPurchaseHistory API in Play Billing Library. If you have seen the previous history record of your subscription item, then you know the user has used his free trial.

Login with a different Google ID through Google Sign-in won't help. Actually, the in-app purchases are tied to the account which downloaded your app. The user really have to completely log out the owner account from device and sign in with a new account to make this abuse.