# Android Trial App

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a trial app
I've searched this place,
no solutions found.

I know on PC some program can impose trial-day limit without reading system time,
how do they do it???

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995719/android-trial-applications/996288#996288) answer your question?

Comment: I know that thread, and it doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this might help: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

Though really, I think you wold have to do trial-day based on system time, still using the licensing service, though.

I personally have not used the app licensing, but glancing over it, it looks like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simple approach will be to store the date when the app is first opened. And each time the app is opened, just check the date and proceed accordingly. You can save the data in either a file or the database.