# How to make an Android application work only for some trial period

Tags: android, trialware

I have an application which should work only for 30 days or few days.

It's just a simple application which has some audio files playing to corresponding to images displayed with some text displayed.

Comment: This isn't a question, it is two statements.

Comment: Can you plz see the answers if this was not a question they have not answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one way to truly achieve this:

> You will have to set up a
>   server, and then whenever your application is started your app sends
>   the phones unique identifier to the server. If the server does not
>   have an entry for that phone id then it makes a new one and notes the
>   time. If the server does have an entry for the phone id then it does a
>   simple check to see if the trial period has expired. It then
>   communicates the results of the trial expiration check back to your
>   application. This approach should not be circumventable, but does
>   require setting up a webserver and such.

There are other ways(such as storing installation date somewhere) but then if user uninstalls your app, that info will be gone and when he reinstalls there is no way to know if he installed before.

EDIT:
Ok, since you want to go with `SharedPreferences` way, here is an example:

```
private final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
private final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String installDate = preferences.getString("InstallDate", null);
    if(installDate == null) {
        // First run, so save the current date
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        Date now = new Date();
        String dateString = formatter.format(now);
        editor.putString("InstallDate", dateString);
        // Commit the edits!
        editor.commit();
    }
    else {
        // This is not the 1st run, check install date
        Date before = (Date)formatter.parse(installDate);
        Date now = new Date();
        long diff = now.getTimeInMillis() - before.getTimeInMillis();
        long days = diff / ONE_DAY;
        if(days > 30) { // More than 30 days?
             // Expired !!!
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I haven't compiled this but should give you an idea.

Comment: I need to achieve that for the time being (Such as storing installation date )can you please provide me some example on that

Comment: right now i dont have any server setup but in the future if i require it what can i do? can i setup a server for free and does all these require internet running ?

Comment: you probably cant setup a server for free. yes, it requires internet connection at least on first run.

Comment: If I change the mobile date what will happen?? If I decrease the date?? Then what happen?? Please let me any know..

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995719/android-trial-applications) is a pretty good answer

To quote the original author - [snctnl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494/snctln)

> Currently most developers accomplish this using one of the following 3
>   techniques.
>
> The first approach is easily circumvented, the first time you run the
>   app save the date/time to a file, database, or shared preferences and
>   every time you run the app after that check to see if the trial period
>   has ended. This is easy to circumvent because uninstalling and
>   reinstalling will allow the user to have another trial period.
>
> The second approach is harder to circumvent, but still circumventable.
>   Use a hard coded time bomb. Basically with this approach you will be
>   hard code an end date for the trial, and all users that download and
>   use the app will stop being able to use the app at the same time. I
>   have used this approach because it is easy to implement and for the
>   most part I just didn't feel like going through the trouble of the
>   third technique. Users can circumvent this by manually changing the
>   date on their phone, but most users won't go through the trouble to do
>   such a thing.
>
> The third technique is the only way that I have heard about to truly
>   be able to accomplish what you want to do. You will have to set up a
>   server, and then whenever your application is started your app sends
>   the phones unique identifier to the server. If the server does not
>   have an entry for that phone id then it makes a new one and notes the
>   time. If the server does have an entry for the phone id then it does a
>   simple check to see if the trial period has expired. It then
>   communicates the results of the trial expiration check back to your
>   application. This approach should not be circumventable, but does
>   require setting up a webserver and such.
>
> It is always good practice to do these checks in the onCreate. If the
>   expiration has ended popup an AlertDialog with a market link to the
>   full version of the app. Only include an "OK" button, and once the
>   user clicks on "OK" make a call to "finish()" to end the activity.