# using Android app for spastic period?

Tags: java, android

How can guarantee that the Android app just will use by example for 10 days? I mean I need to make trial version for my app?

I am try using **SharedPreferences** but when I change the date in Android device Sitting, the app. can used? (I see it is easy to break it!!)

I suggest to use counter to count after any readen date by **SharedPreferences**; but also I don't know if that possible or no? I mean after one day increase the value of counter 1 ?!

any suggestion will be appreciated ..

Many thanks,

Comment: Are you distributing your app through play store?

Comment: Unfortunately, No !! it is for Special company purposes uses?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using play store to distribute your apk, You can use [Subscriptions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) to set a trial period. In your case, the simplest way you have is to use a web service to keep track of the users who are using it.

Something like:

1. Get the IMEI of the device.
2. Register it on your server
3. Every time the app starts, check through the server if the trial period is still to expire.

There is no way you can prevent the user from removing all your files or from resetting the device. So an "App Only" solution does not exist. You will have to use some web service to register devices.

Comment: Cool...I was also looking for this...!!

Answer (score 1):

You should read this post:
[Creating an Android trial application that expires after a fixed time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995719/creating-an-android-trial-application-that-expires-after-a-fixed-time-period)

Seems like the only reliable way to acomplish this, is to catch the install date + unique identifier of mobile phone, and send it to an own server to check the validity.

Comment: yes truly thanks, really I read it before! but I do not need to use server? since the check will be offline?!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot guarantee that. No matter what you try, as the app runs on the user's device, he can manipulate the binary until it will run on his system despite any checks you put into it. All you can do is to encourage the user to pay and make it more difficult for the ones that won't pay.

There are several techniques for this, most involve a check against a server, but that for once requires the infrastructure and for second can be a privacy issue in some countries (and good luck on receiving that request from China behind the great digital wall). A different technique is to give the user a gift for buying the full version. That is pretty similar to the lite/full versions you often see in all stores. Beside that you can give a user certain features that absolutely require a verifiable registration (like extra storage on a server or free updates).