# How can I get Android installed time for Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm looking for a way to make a trial version of my app.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995719/creating-an-android-trial-application-that-expires-after-a-fixed-time-period) that describes tree ways of doing it.

I thought about another way, if I could get the time the application was installed (from Google Play) I could make a period of time starting form this date and it won't matter if the user change the device or clear the data or do anything else.

Is it possible to do this... How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get such time from Google Play.