# get time from server to close to do trial

Tags: android

I want to make checking about the current time of the server and check if my application passed that day , then the application should stop working

I made a research but I wasnt able to make it working as many examples I think they missing some thing

for example this post

[Creating an Android trial application that expires after a fixed time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995719/creating-an-android-trial-application-that-expires-after-a-fixed-time-period)

I see it uses extends BaseMainActivity
where is the "BaseMainActivity" so I can extend it !!

and how the checking for the date and time get should be done

and should I use alarm manager to check that server for the time ? or there is another better solutions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they're probably just using a custom class as the base activity. You could try changing it to simply `Activity` or `ActionBarActivity` if you're using the v7 support library.

Comment: ok , I have done that but how to start checking from the main activity if that isnt the main activity - I thought that I can use `checkExpiry()` but I found that another function call it - so how can I used that new class from the main activity?

Comment: Don't really follow what you mean. You could just make it the launcher activity? If you're using the example code you linked, it doesn't look like it's a complete solution and just grabs the current time for a URL. You really need to look at the correct answer and implement the third suggestion for a robust solution.

Comment: I want to use some thing to check the current time from server and make comparision , is there any sample for that ?