# Android demo or trial app

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

im creating an Android app and i want to put it on Google Play. I want the users to download it, use and test it for about 7 days and then, the app will be blocked and the user has to buy it to continue using it.

I've tried with Backup Manager but it didnt work.

Then i read about [Licensing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) (i have a good tutorial already) but i dont know if its what i need.

Other option is to make a subscrition payment to use, but with a free trial, however this is a bad option because the user has to put the payment method and data to use the app.

What do you think guys? can i use Licensing for what i need or better other tecnology?

**EDIT:**

Maybe i didnt explain myself very good, i want to know if with the Licensing system i can do a trial version of an app for like 7 days. I've tried the other solutions and didnt work for me (Backup Manager, SharedPreferences...) and want to know if Licensing can help me or if its another technology i can use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an Android trial application that expires after a fixed time period](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995719/creating-an-android-trial-application-that-expires-after-a-fixed-time-period)

Comment: no, i've tried all on that answer and didnt work for me, i need other technology

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solutions for what you want.

Google provides a [Subscriptions trial](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#trials) with their Subscriptions library, but then the users should pay "regularly" for the content of your app. (weekly, monthly or yearly etc..)

The best option for your use case in my opinion should be this:

1. You setup your app as FREE on the store
2. When the user download the app the first time, you create some sort of key which identify your installation on that device
3. After trial period ends, you can block the app usage until the user purchase an In-App item which re-enable the app functionality.

This is some sort of FREE/PRO version logic which a lot of developers already use in the store.

Comment: yes, but in that way i will need a server with a database, and i want to avoid that

Comment: You can't achieve what you need without a server and a database or using the licensing library, because it's stated in the first 6 lines of the Licensing Overview page: "Google Play considers a user to be licensed if the user is a recorded purchaser of the application". And that's not your case

Comment: oh, i see... Thank you, i will continue with my search